# Codeigniter function, pass data from $data array to $this->email->message('INCLUDING HERE A DATA ARRAY VALUE');

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, variables

i am a learner and i write this code:

```
public function send_message()
    {

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

        $data                       =  array();
        $data['message_name']       = $this->input->post('name');
        $data['message_email']      = $this->input->post('email');
        $data['message_phone']      = $this->input->post('phone');
        $data['message_value']      = $this->input->post('message');

        $this->load->model('service_model');
        $query = $this->service_model->send_message($data);


    $config = Array(
   'protocol' => 'sendmail',
   'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
   'smtp_port' => 465
 );
$this->load->library('email',$config);

        $this->email->from('xx@xx.es');
        $this->email->to("xx@gmail.com");
        $this->email->subject('CLIENT MESSAGE');
        $this->email->message('<h1>HERE I WANT TO PUT ALL ARRAY VALUES -name, email, phone and message ... from $data</h1>');
        $this->email->send();



        if($query)
            echo "Thank you for write!";
        else
            echo "Message fail!";
    }
```

how can i do the question???

i only want to send the $data values (message_name,message_email,message_phone,message_value) somethink like this into the email message in HTML simple code or plain text:

Yo have recived a message from $data['message_name'] from mail $data['message_email'] and phone $data['message_phone']:

$data['message_value']

how can i do this?

I am using codeigniter and getting the $data from a phonegap remote app.

thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$this->email->message(
    'Hi my name is' .$data['message_name'].
    'And my email is' .$data['message_email'].
    'Phone' .$data['message_phone'].
    'Message:' .$data['message_value']
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$data['message_name']       = $this->input->post('name');
$data['message_email']      = $this->input->post('email');
$data['message_phone']      = $this->input->post('phone');
$data['message_value']      = $this->input->post('message');

$message = '<h1>';
$message .= $data['message_name'].',';
$message .= $data['message_email'].',';
$message .= $data['message_phone'].',';
$message .= $data['message_value'].',';
$message .= '</h1>';

$this->email->message($message);
```